# Combining results of multiple subqueries in one set

Tags: mysql, set, subquery

I am trying to exclude rows in my table based on the id's in other tables.
I have 2 tables of which a "select * from" results in a set like (1,2,3)

I am trying to combine the results from these 2 subqueries into one, like:

```
(1,2,3) + (4,5) = (1,2,3,4,5)
```

So I can filter the big table with a "NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5)"

I have been looking at GROUP_CONCAT's, UNION and all other kinds, but I can't seem to find something that actually works.

Anyone have a idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
from Table3 
where id not in (
    select id from Table1 --your subquery that returns 1,2,3
    union all
    select id from Table2 --your subquery that returns 4,5
)
```

Comment: The "all" is unnecessary. You don't want a sub-list with repeated values. Just UNION or to be explicit UNION DISTINCT. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Comment: @LastCoder Not the case. Removing `ALL` requires the query to do extra work (sorting) to remove duplicates. E.g., if the first item in the list is matched, this is wasted effort. This is the same reason you should not use `DISTINCT` when building a subquery for use in an `IN` clause.

Comment: This is very interesting could you elaborate on the internals of this if possible. Seems like the UNION DISTINCT would yield a HashSet ADT to be used by the main query, would the UNION ALL also (thus ignoring the repeated values anyways)? You're saying the UNION DISTINCT would always cause sorting to force the distinctness even though programmatically it doesn't seem necessary (since building the Set in both the ALL and DISTINCT case would be O(N)).

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from mytable
where id not in (
    select id from othertable
    union
    select id from othertable2
)
```